# How to remove lines that have Hyphens, Numbers and a spesific TLDs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a txt file that have domains name in it.

```
asd.com
ass.net
sdf.info
as-er.net
019-ne.com
012.com
01dc.net
```

I want these

```
asd.com
```

first I want to delete lines that have Hyphens, Numbers no matter the extension.
I dont want to delete .com lines. I want to delete .net, .org, .info etc lines And also if there is hyphens or numbers in a line .com can be deleted as well otherwise i dont want to remove .com lines I want to collect only .com lines that don't have dumbers and hyphens

How can i do this with Notepad++

Thanks

Comment: So _“and except .com TLD”_ means what exactly? You want to leave those rows alone, regardless of whether they contain hyphens/digits? You want to remove all rows that have a _different_ TLD? And what have you tried so far? Please not this site is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to show us your efforts first of all. [ask]

Comment: I dont want to delete .com lines.
I want to delete .net, .org, .info etc lines
And also if there is hyphens or numbers in a line .com can be deleted as well otherwise i dont want to remove .com lines

I want to collect only .com lines that don't have dumbers and hyphens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^(?:.*(?!\.com)\.\w+|.*[0-9-].*)\R
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
^                     from the start of the line
(?:                   match EITHER of the following two patterns
    .*(?!\.com)\.\w+  match anything NOT ending in .com
    |                 OR
    .*[0-9-].*        match anything which has a digit or hyphen
)
\R                    OS independent line ending
```

Comment: I think i made a mistake and i edited my post

Comment: @Mecra Check the updated answer and demo, it seems to be working (haven't tested against NPP though).